# Proving which QM interpretation is correct

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity, quantum-interpretations

Let's assume that the existence of gravitons is theoretically proven or they are detected by LHC could one interpretaion be proven correct?

Answer (score 2):

The interpretations of quantum mechanics are different ontologies which lead to equivalent mathematics. If physics is at some level the construction of mathematical models for reality, then we should always expect this sort of ontological redundancy.

If a model of quantum gravity did not permit this sort of redundancy it would be extremely surprising, and all that gravitons give us is "some of the models of quantum gravity (the ones without gravitons) are unable to model certain phenomena," not "here is the uniquely correct theory of quantum gravity," so you would also have theory-level redundancy at a higher scale.