# Proving which Quantum Mechanics interpretation is correct

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity, quantum-interpretations

Let's assume that the existence of gravitons is theoretically proven or they are detected by LHC could one interpretaion be proven correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving which QM interpretation is correct](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384477/)

Comment: If your question is closed, please don't just ask the same question verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The word interpretation and the concept of "proof" are incompatible. One can prove a theorem in an axiomatic mathematical theory, and write "quod erat demonstrandum." Physics theories use axiomatic mathematics and impose extra axioms called "postulates", "laws" "principles" to choose a subset of the mathematical solutions that fit the data; modeling the data is the objective.

You are enumerating different physics models which use different mathematics to fit the data , and you are assuming they all fit the data well, with equal accuracy within errors . If this ever becomes true, there is no way to chose between the mathematics, and call that "real". The only comparison tool would be simplicity of calculations.

Here is an example of using complete sets of functions to mathematically model a photograph.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTh3u.png

The photograph is the data which is modeled by the mathematics in a series expansion using fourier transforms and summed on the right. The physical theoretical model.

One interpretation is given by these α β γ ... that build up the photograph, based on fourier transforms.

Suppose another set of complete functions did the same mathematical job as well as the α β γ above, call them a b c d ..... Do you see a way of proving one as correct/real and the other as false/unreal as long as the exact photo is reproduced?

In physics it is the data that always check a mathematical theory. If two theories explain equally well the same data, the only choice is simplicity of calculations, not "correct" because they are both correct in describing the objective, the data. -anna v